# Equivalent of dplyr rowwsie combn in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have this code which performs combn on all the values of a particular dataframe. It is done by using dplyr rowwise

```
library(dplyr,warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
Column1<-c("red","blue")#creating column1
Column2<-c("green","white")#creating column2
Column3<-c("aqua","magenta")#creating column2
df_1<-data.frame(Column1, Column2, Column3)#creating data frame
df_2 <- df_1 %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(COMB=list(combn(c_across(Column1:Column3),2,simplify = FALSE))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = COMB) %>% 
  unnest(cols=COMB)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It results in following

```
| \# A tibble: 12 x 4                |
|------------------------------------|
|    Column1 Column2 Column3 COMB    |
|    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   |
|  1 red     green   aqua    red     |
|  2 red     green   aqua    green   |
|  3 red     green   aqua    red     |
|  4 red     green   aqua    aqua    |
|  5 red     green   aqua    green   |
|  6 red     green   aqua    aqua    |
|  7 blue    white   magenta blue    |
|  8 blue    white   magenta white   |
|  9 blue    white   magenta blue    |
| 10 blue    white   magenta magenta |
| 11 blue    white   magenta white   |
| 12 blue    white   magenta magenta |
```

Is it possible to perform a rowwise combn function in data.table. For e.g. on the following

```
library(data.table)
Column1<-c("red","blue")#creating column1
Column2<-c("green","white")#creating column2
Column3<-c("aqua","magenta")#creating column2
df_1<-data.table(Column1, Column2, Column3)#creating DT
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can create the 'COMB' using `Map`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_1)[, COMB := list(do.call(Map, c(f1, .SD)))]
```

where

```
f1 <- function(...) combn(c(...), m = 2, simplify = FALSE)
```

---

Or if we want to expand the rows

```
out <- df_1[, grp := seq_len(.N)][df_1[,
      combn(unlist(.SD), 2), .(grp)], on = .(grp)][, grp := NULL]
setnames(out, 'V1', 'COMB')
```

-output

```
out
#    Column1 Column2 Column3    COMB
# 1:     red   green    aqua     red
# 2:     red   green    aqua   green
# 3:     red   green    aqua     red
# 4:     red   green    aqua    aqua
# 5:     red   green    aqua   green
# 6:     red   green    aqua    aqua
# 7:    blue   white magenta    blue
# 8:    blue   white magenta   white
# 9:    blue   white magenta    blue
#10:    blue   white magenta magenta
#11:    blue   white magenta   white
#12:    blue   white magenta magenta
```

Comment: Many thanks @akrun. "out" was the desired result I was looking for. It worked beautifully.  I am new to data.table and I have a follow up question for you. Instead of Column1, Column2, Column3 if the DT consisted of Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5 and I wanted to pass only Column1, Column4, Column5 as x in combn(x,2), how can I adapt your solution `df_1[, grp := seq_len(.N)][df_1[, combn(unlist(.SD), 2), .(grp)], on = .(grp)][, grp := NULL]` to that?

Comment: AFAIR Map only wraps to mapply, and API of mapply was always easier for me to work with.

Comment: If there are unwanted combn columns present in DT, then adapting akrun's solution to that scenario `df_1<-data.table(Column1, Column1_1, Column2, Column2_1, Column3)
out <- df_1[, grp := seq_len(.N)]
out1<-out[df_1[,combn(unlist(.SD), 2), by=.(grp,Column1_1,Column2_1)], on = .(grp,Column1_1,Column2_1)]
out1[,!c("Column1_1","Column2_1","grp")]` where Column1_1 and Column2_1 are unwanted in combn

Answer (score 3):

You can get the data in long format and create combinations for each row.

```
library(data.table)

df_1[, row := seq_len(.N)]
df_2 <- melt(df_1, id.vars = 'row')
df_1[df_2[, combn(value, 2), row], on = 'row'][, row := NULL][]

#    Column1 Column2 Column3      V1
# 1:     red   green    aqua     red
# 2:     red   green    aqua   green
# 3:     red   green    aqua     red
# 4:     red   green    aqua    aqua
# 5:     red   green    aqua   green
# 6:     red   green    aqua    aqua
# 7:    blue   white magenta    blue
# 8:    blue   white magenta   white
# 9:    blue   white magenta    blue
#10:    blue   white magenta magenta
#11:    blue   white magenta   white
#12:    blue   white magenta magenta
```